# History.pushState creates large amout of entries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create something like a dynamic page, but I have this problem. When I fire `history.pushState` it creates large amount of history entries, even though the action that fires it is run only once. My code is as follows:

```
    var url = 'http://localhost:8888/depeche-mode/violator'; // example url

    var plainUrl = url + '/?plain',
        startUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/',
        newUrl = url.replace(startUrl, '#/');

    $('#content').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 250, function() {
        $('#content').load(plainUrl +' #content > *', function(response) {
            $('#content').animate({opacity:1}, 250, function() {
            document.title = pageTitle;
            Posts.historyHash(newUrl);
        });
        });
    });
```

edit:

```
var Posts = {
    historyHash: function(newUrl) {
        window.location.hash = newUrl;
        $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
            var url = window.location.hash,
                nohash = url.replace('#',''),
                properUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/'+nohash;
                history.pushState('','',newUrl);
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is very serious when I want to use `Back` button in my browser - I need to click it couple of times before I actually get to change the url. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `historyHash` when you load content, and `historyHash` registers an event handler on `window` — **every time** you call it. So you end up with a bunch of event handlers for the `hashchange` event.

You presumably only want one. Either just register one, or unregister the previous ones when registering a new one.

I can't quite tell which of those you want, but as the handler uses the `newUrl`, it may well be that you want to unregister previous handlers. If so, probably best to use an event namespace so you only unregister your own handlers:

```
var Posts = {
    historyHash: function(newUrl) {
        window.location.hash = newUrl;
        $(window)
            .unbind('hashchange.historyhash')             // Out with the old
            .bind('hashchange.historyhash', function() {  // In with the new
                var url = window.location.hash,
                    nohash = url.replace('#',''),
                    properUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/'+nohash;
                    history.pushState('','',newUrl);
            });
    }
}
```

Although looking at it, you could just use a single handler and remember `newUrl` on `Posts`:

```
var Posts = {
    historyHash: function(newUrl) {
        window.location.hash = newUrl;
        this.newUrl = newUrl;
    }
};
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    var url, nohash, properUrl;
    if (Posts.newUrl) {
        url = window.location.hash,
        nohash = url.replace('#',''),
        properUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/'+nohash;
        history.pushState('','',Posts.newUrl);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't say I understand completely. I'm calling `historyHash` once after each load, because I want to have continuity in history. (that's why I use `pushState` not `replaceState`). How can I, like you said, register "just one"?

Comment: @TomekBuszewski: The issue is registering the handler repeatedly, not calling `pushState` (that part's fine). But say you call `historyHash` three times: You end up with **three** `hashchange` event handlers: The first calsl `pushState` with its `newUrl`, the second with *its* `newUrl`, and the third with ***its*** `newUrl`. As you were commenting I was adding a couple of examples of how you could have just a single `hashchange` handler at any given time. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for you code, but I still get four history entires after one click (I tried both solutions).

Comment: @TomekBuszewski: You'll need to replicate it with an [MCVE](/help/mcve) and post it to the question, I'm afraid.

Comment: I tried, but I don't know how to replicate `load` on jsfiddle.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski: Doesn't have to be live, if you give all the relevant code and such. Both `load` and `pushState` will make it hard to do this on any of the "live" sites (or here as a Stack Snippet). I'm heading out, but presumably someone will be able to help. Good luck with it,